# Identity specification not working in Linq

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use linq to insert a row into a table, and the ID column of the table has an identify specification:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(36,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [OccurredDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Event] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have the identity specification accounted for in my DBML file in my Visual Studio project:

```
[Table(Name="dbo.Event")]
public partial class Event : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  /* ... */
  [Column(Storage="_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
  public int ID
  {
    /* ... */
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

What's going wrong?  When I try to insert like this:

```
Data.Event myEvent = new Data.Event();

myEvent.Description = summaryText;
db.Events.InsertOnSubmit(myEvent);                    
db.SubmitChanges();
```

the following exception is thrown:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value
>   NULL into column 'ID', table
>   'redacted.dbo.Event'; column does not
>   allow nulls.  INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated

Answer (score 0):

I tried this setup - works like a charm for me. I can insert a new `Event` object - no problem at all - and I do get back the new ID right away....

Are you sure your database and model are in sync?? Is the table maybe not really created with an `INT IDENTITY` ??

Comment: I think I had the wrong database specified in a connection string.  Still trying to get my test set up to verify...